# SemVer, Helm Charts and Build Numbers

Tags: continuous-integration, kubernetes-helm, continuous-delivery, semantic-versioning

I have been struggling with the way SemVer is setup and how it is used by Helm Charts.  The issue seems to stem from these two facts:

- SemVer does not allow build numbers in release builds.
- Helm Charts do not have a way to "Promote" a pre-release package.

While in development I need build numbers (ie 2.5.0-build.12, 2.5.0-build.13).  This is needed so that development revisions can be built and deployed to a development environment.  I create a container with these prerelease version numbers and then put it into a Helm Chart with the same pre-release version.

But then I am ready to go to production.  At this point the container image is easy, I can just add another tag (ie 2.5.0).  But the Helm Chart is not so easy.  I can't just release the helm chart I had.  It has a prerelease version number in the chart.yaml.  (Chart.yaml cannot be overridden).  I have to download the helm chart, un-package it, update the update the chart.yaml with the new version number, repackage it and upload it.  And since I use sub-charts, I have to do this for each of the charts in my product (and then upload the product chart).

I can do all that.  It is a bit brittle, but I can make it work.  But before I do, I wanted to ask if there is some non-prerelease way that SemVer can keep build information (and still understand version precedence of that build) OR if there is a way that Helm can upgrade a chart to be a release version (similar to tagging a container image)?